# Remove file icon from toolbar

Tags: icon, menu-bar

I don't know how the shortcut file icon got stuck on the toolbar

[image]

Any idea how to remove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click the toolbar and select "Customize toolbar", then drag the icon away from it.

[image: Right click and select "Customize Toolbar"]

[image: Drag icon from the toolbar]